# R Shiny autoresizing wellPanel using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, r, shiny, frontend

I want to add to my Shiny app floting `wellPanel` which resizes when `shinydashboard` sidebar is collapsed. I prepared MWE:

`app.R`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
    # Setting id makes input$tabs give the tabName of currently-selected tab
    id = "tabs",
    menuItem(
      "Dashboard",
      tabName = "dashboard",
      icon = icon("dashboard")
    )
  )),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$head(tags$script(src = "resize.js")),
    div(
      id = "myPanel",
      style = "left:0px; right:0px; bottom:0px; position:fixed; cursor:inherit; z-index: 10000;",
      wellPanel(id = "myWellPanel",
        style = "padding: 8px; border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC; background: #FFFFEE;",
        HTML("Save changes?"),
        actionButton("save", "Save"),
        actionButton("cancel", "Cancel")
      )
    )
    )
  )

server <- function(input, output) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

`www/resize.js`:

```
function resizeWellPanel(collapsed) {
    console.log('Resizing wellPanel');
    var itemWidth = $('#tabs').width();
    var availWidth = $(window).innerWidth();
    var difference = availWidth - itemWidth;
    console.log('itemWidth: ' + itemWidth + '; availWidth: ' + availWidth + '; difference: ' + difference);
    el=$('#myWellPanel');
    if (collapsed == "true") {
      console.log("is collapsed: " + collapsed);
      $('#myWellPanel').css('margin-left', 2 + 'px');
      el.innerWidth(availWidth - 2); // set width depending on sidebar
    } else if (collapsed === false) {
      console.log("is collapsed: " + collapsed);
      el.innerWidth(difference); // set width depending on sidebar
      $('#myWellPanel').css('margin-left', 2 + itemWidth + 'px');
    } else {
        throw new Error('Did nothing');
   }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  collapseStatus = $('.main-sidebar.shiny-bound-input').attr("data-collapsed");
  console.log("collapseStatus: ", + collapseStatus);
  resizeWellPanel(collapseStatus);

  $('.main-sidebar.shiny-bound-input').change(function() {
    collapseStatus = $(this).attr("data-collapsed");
    setTimeout(function(collapseStatus) {
      resizeWellPanel(collapseStatus);
    }, 500);
  });
});
```

But I encountered two problems:

1. `collapseStatus` variable is `NaN`- why? Command `$('.main-sidebar.shiny-bound-input').attr("data-collapsed")` returns `true/false` value.
2. Function `$('.main-sidebar.shiny-bound-input').change(function() { ...` does not trigger when sidebar is collapsed. It is strange because when you copy-paste JS code to web browser console it is triggered.

[image]